# Dynamic RNN padding and indexing to match ground truth

Tags: python, indexing, tensorflow, tensor

I am running an RNN (many-to-many). I have a different time dimension for each user. E.g. user 1 has 5-time stamps and user 2 has 8-time stamps, etc. I think the RNN accepts only tensors with constant dimensions, so I currently pad (not using tensorflow) the time dimension with zeros till it reaches the maximum time stamps (max_user_time) among all users in the batch. For example, if user #1 has 2 time stamps and 3 features I get a tensor with dimensions [1,2,3]:

```
|1 2|
|2 5|
|6 3|
```

If user 3 in the batch has 3 time stamps, then we need to add paading such that user 1 has a tensor with dimensions [1,3,3]:

```
|1 2 0|
|2 5 0|
|6 3 0|
```

The padding for each user will be of different length.

Is there a way to get this using tf.pad or something similar for all users at once?

After padding, I pass these tensors as input to the RNN and reshape the output:

```
outputs,states=tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell,inputs=input
                                     ,dtype=tf.float32,sequence_length=max_batch)

reshape_out=tf.reshape(outputs,[-1,n_hidden])
```

For the sequence length parameter, I pass a vector with the timestamps for each user, so expecting a zero output if a user has passed its max time - according to [tf.dynamic_rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) documentation.

So, I get from reshaping a tensor sized [batch_sizeXmax_user_time,n_hidden].

This is a bigger tensor than the ground truth tesnor, which is smaller and has rows for each user according to its timestamps.

Is there an easy way to use tensorflow to pick only the rows that are observed in order to calculate the loss?